# A property with the name 'httpRequest' is not present

Tags: wcf, azure

I've ran into an interesting problem using the Azure Service Management API. Specifically, when I try any operation, I get a "Server Error in '/' Application.
A property with the name 'httpRequest' is not present. ".

This only happens in **one** project and I can't reproduce it with creating other projects.

I've tried reading Fusion logs, because I've suspected there's a problem with assembly versions, but it turns out not to be the case.
I also tried readding references, which also didn't work.

I'm stuck  - does anybody have a clue?

```
<InnerException i:nil="true"></InnerException>
    <Message>A property with the name 'httpRequest' is not present.</Message>
<StackTrace>
Server stack trace:
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties.get_Item(String name)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.ClientOutputMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(Message& request, IClientChannel channel) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.BeforeSendRequest(ProxyRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.PrepareCall(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Boolean oneway, ProxyRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeBeginService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]:
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
</StackTrace>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is described in detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/07/19/webchannelfactory-inside-a-wcf-service.aspx). But you need a nudge  in the right direction, which is nutoriously difficult to find. We've had the same issue a while ago so I've written a blog post [about httpRequest not being present exception](http://lab.studiopesec.com/a-property-with-the-name-httprequest-is-not-present/) (WCF).

To summarize, wrap your call to the code in:

```
    using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)channel))
    {
       // ... my code
    }
```

Comment: What is this "channel"? I'm receiving the same error when trying to make a SOAP call

Comment: Please consult the original link I referenced in the solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/07/19/webchannelfactory-inside-a-wcf-service.aspx It should give you more details about that.

Comment: Your blog post link is dead, which is why its better to post a full answer here.

Comment: Dead link, incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to just add the httpResponse property when its missing:

```
    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        if (!reply.Properties.Any(p => p.Key == "httpResponse"))
            reply.Properties.Add("httpResponse", new HttpResponseMessageProperty());

        var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
        httpHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        httpHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
    }
```